# neo4j 5 HTTP API how to send multiple queries coroutine?

Tags: neo4j

neo4j 5 provides HTTP API here https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/transactions/
it can execute multiple queries, but in the description, the multiple queries runs in sequence.
I want to run 20 read queries, it will be slow, is there any way to run them coroutine or parallel?

Use Golang HTTP to run 20 queries in a http request, it is slowly.